# Simple Registration 1.6.1 compatible with and EE3.5.10?

Tags: members, registration

Simple Registration displays error messages after installation

> Only variables should be assigned by reference
>
> user/addons/simple_registration/libraries/ab/ab_common.php, line 19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report.

This was a PHP7 compatibility issue that has been fixed in 1.6.2. Please download the latest version.